# How to Auto Renew Message Timeout using ServiceBusTrigger in Azure Function with C#?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

When using the `ServiceBusTrigger` with Azure Functions to trigger the function to execute on new messages in a Service Bus Queue, their doesn't seem to be a way to auto renew the message timeout. Sure, you can always call the `BrokeredMessage.RenewLock` method, but with Functions there appears to be no way to configure it to auto renew the message lock.

Is there a way anyone has found to configure an Azure Function to Auto Renew the BrokeredMessage lock while a Service Bus Queue message is being processed?

Yes, I know you can increase the default timeout on the Service Bus Queue, but the maximum configurable default timeout is 5 minutes; which can still be too short .

Thanks!

Here's an example of using the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute in C# when building an Azure Function like mentioned using Visual Studio. Notice, the `ServiceBusTrigger` usage does not allow a Timeout Duration to be set, or an Auto Renew to be configured either.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction1")]
public static async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "AzureServiceBus")] BrokeredMessage sbCommand,
    ILogger log)
{
    // process message here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function renews the message lock by itself. You don't need to renew the lock manually, it is handled by the run time of the function. Please refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior).

Comment: Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior